# Using a filename for a variable and move similar files with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a powershell script that will look at a directory(c:\Temp) and look for files with exensions of .fin.
If it finds a file with the fin extension I need it to move all files that have the same first seven characters of that fin file to another directory(c:\Temp\fin).
There could be multiple .fin files at a time in that directory with files that need to be moved. 
I have tried a few different things but I am new to anything like this. I have only used very basic powershell scripts or commands. While this might be basic(not sure) I am lost as to where to start.

Comment: Please show some of the things you tried, what didn't work, what did work, and what you expected to happen via an [edit] to your post that includes a [mcve] of your attempts so far.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to call Get-ChildItem twice.  The first time to get the pattern you want to match the file names to and the second to get the files.  You can then pipe the results of the second command to Move-Item.  Here's an example of how to do that:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    $DirectoryToScan,
    $ExtensionToMatch = ".fin",
    $TargetDirectory
)

$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $DirectoryToScan -File

foreach ($File in $Files) {
    if($File.Extension -eq $ExtensionToMatch) {
        $PatternToMatch = "$($File.BaseName.Substring(0, 7))*$ExtensionToMatch"
        Write-Verbose "PatternToMatch: $PatternToMatch"
        $MatchedFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $DirectoryToScan -Filter $PatternToMatch
    }

    $MatchedFiles | Move-Item -Destination $TargetDirectory
}
```

If you save the above into a file called Move-MatchingFiles.ps1 you can pass in your parameters `Moving-MatchingFiles.ps1 -DirectoryToScan C:\Temp -TargetDirectory C:\Temp\fin`.  The ExtensionToMatch parameter is optional and only needed if you wanted to move a different type of file.

Comment: @SpecialAgent666 did this answer help with your problem?  Let me know if there's anything I can clarify